# Installing Ubuntu stand only help

Tags: system-installation

I'm new to Ubuntu and I was hoping to install it on my old Windows XP computer but if there is a way I would prefer to have only Ubuntu on the computer rather than have both Ubuntu and Windows. I wanted to do this method because Windows XP is no longer getting support and I wanted to keep my network safe. I tried looking up things on the internet and youtube but I've been having a lot of difficulty. I managed to get it on the computer but it was through Windows. I then tried creating a bootable version of it with a usb stick but I wasn't having any luck with that. I tried making the dvd disk multiple times but it never worked.

Comment: Please provide more information about the trouble you are having with USB or DVD.

Comment: Try creating bootable usb with [LiLu](http://www.linuxliveusb.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First of all** make sure that your computer is able to boot up DVD's or USB units from the BIOS. (BIOS is the low graphic system just after starting the computer up).

When you start your computer, make sure to enter the BIOS menu by hitting either F2, F!, ESC or even try F9. I don't know what pc-model you have, you may want to search that up if possible.

So, when you have done that, search up any option related to the boot order of your system devices. If you find such an option, make sure to place the USB in front of your hard-drives in your boot order, then save the setup, and try to boot from the USB pen again.

However, if this doesn't work, make sure to visit [www.ubuntu.com](http://www.ubuntu.com) and read carefully about installing ubuntu from Windows.

Good luck with your installation, that is the best answer i can give based on your information you provided here.

Comment: Thank you the boot order is what it was, now I think all I have to do is uninstall windows with the os uninstaller correct? Also if I needed to upgrade the one I have to a newer one do I have to make a new dvd or is there a way to upgrade / change it? My last question is do I have to have the dvd in at all times to run it or can I remove it after I uninstall Windows?

Comment: When you put in the DVD/USB with Ubuntu on, you can permanently delete Windows by formatting the hard-drive (note that this will erease everything on the harddrive). And you can upgrade ubuntu by using the Software-updater tool on ubuntu, you don't need to have the newest version available on the USB or DVD. And you don't have to use the DVD every time you use Ubuntu, ubuntu will be installed just like windows :) If you ever should face problems, you know where to find me or www.askubuntu.com ^^

Comment: How should I go about reformatting the hard drive with the dvd? I think my problem is that I may have burned it onto the dvd incorrectly. Even on the OS uninstaller rather then call it Ubuntu it says that it is Ubuntu installed in Windows.

Comment: That is easily described in the installation. When you install Ubuntu, you will get asked if you want to install ubuntu alongside windows, or if you want to remove windows, and install ubuntu. When you get asked, just click 'remove windows and install ubuntu' - That should do it for you. The installer is really easy to understand, and it is all described with pictures on the web, if you just search for it ^^ Good luck :P